# HTML List items moving underneath each other when screen is too small

Tags: html, css

I have a list with about 5 items in it. When I scale the window down they start going underneath each other or going to the other side of the screen.

How it's supposed to look:
[image]

How it looks when downscaled:
[image]

```css
.navitem {
  animation-name: Nnavitemhover;
  animation-duration: 0.25s;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 2vmin;
  padding: 3.25vmin;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background: #574c4f;
  color: white;
  word-wrap: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="navtitle"> AttributeError Developing </li>
  <li class="navitem" id="wd"> item 1 </li>
  <li class="navitem" id="rs"> item 2 </li>
  <li class="navitem" id="dbd"> item 3 </li>
  <li class="navitem" id="c"> item 4 </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navitem {
    animation-name: Nnavitemhover;
    animation-duration: 0.25s;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 2vmin;
    padding: 3.25vmin;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background: #574c4f;
    color: white;
    word-wrap: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="navtitle"> AttributeError Developing </li>
<li class="navitem" id="wd"> item 1 </li>
<li class="navitem" id="rs"> item 2 </li>
<li class="navitem" id="dbd"> item 3 </li>
<li class="navitem" id="c"> item 4 </li>
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: CSS or HTML code?

Comment: both the best is to do a reproducable code snippet

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: Are the list elements overlapping each other, or are there any other elements? I tried your code in Codepen and I didn't find any issue. @AttributeError

Comment: Can you share your the `Nnavitemhover` animation too?

Comment: The animation only changes background color and font color.

Comment: And they only overlap each other when the window is really small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention what you wanted as a result, so this answer only prevents the item from wrapping.

You can use the `white-space: nowrap` CSS property on your `.navitem`. And if you need, apply it to the surrounding `<ul>` too.